# Unable to login & register to Django dashboard

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I am having below Django dashboard project:

https://github.com/wittymindstech/IoTGlobalMap

I cloned this repo and executed:

```
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py runserver
```

In the login dashboard when i am entering username and password, it says username and password doesn't match.

Attached is the screenshots.[image: login issue]

[image: Login issue]

[image: Register issue]

Below is the terminal output:

```
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 10, 2020 - 13:13:33
Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'GlobDash.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:39] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3628
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:39] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3628
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:42] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3670
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:42] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3628
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:45] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3953
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:45] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3953
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:58] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3965
[10/Jul/2020 13:13:58] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3953
```

Comment: please post your relevant codes here instead of github repo

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py createsuperuser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to forgot to [create a superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-an-admin-user)?

`python manage.py createsuperuser`